# How to get a newline in Python shell, with a different indentation, without breaking the code

Tags: syntax, newline

I want to this in Python Shell

```html
def get_tweets(xyz) :
 auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
 for j in tweets_for_csv:
  tmp.append(j) 
                print(tmp)
```

But, in the last line, on clicking [Enter], It becomes this

```html
def get_tweets(xyz) :
 auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
 for j in tweets_for_csv:
  tmp.append(j) 
        print(tmp)
```

See the difference in an ​indentation in the last line of expected and actual code.

Please, help me to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, by myself. I am a newbie, and also coding after a long time.

Use Backspace, to change indentation. I was aware of this but in the subconscious mind.